# Quantile regression and prediction estimate

Tags: regression, machine-learning, distributions, modeling, quantile-regression

I am working on a personal project and I've been wondering about something.

I'm basically taking some loan data from kaggle, analysing/cleaning it, then trying to apply machine/deep learning models to it.

One of the models I want to try to use and get LGD estimates is quantile regression. From what I've been reading quantile regression is mostly used to get a better understanding of the target's distribution by estimating conditional quantiles. So not as a prediction tool, at least it may be less straighforward than linear regression in that regard.

Anyways, the distribution I have looks like this
[image: Loss Given Default Distribution]

[image: PDF]

I think my estimated value should be a weighted sum of the lgd values associated with the modes of my distribution, but even this idea is quite vague, and has no statistical basis.
If we consider the "two" modes here, I am thinking of taking the 15% or 25% percentile depending on where my first mode is, then the 85% or 75% percentile, or whatever other percentile of modes, take those lgds and weight them by those number of occurences.

The main problem I have with this is that I am unsure if this is sound, and I end up having to look at the distribution myself to decide on my quantile values for regression. So human jugdement at the end of the day.